# If partitioner class creates more than one partitions but number of reduce tasks are set to less

Tags: mapreduce

How many reduce tasks will be launched and how many output files will be created if my partitioner class is returning n partitions and in the main function I have job.setNumReduceTasks(1) ?

Answer (score 1):

1. At a time only one partition will be running because you have set `job.setNumReduceTasks(1)`.
2. Number of output files will be n, because all the partitions eventually get processed. The Reducer tasks will restart if the data is left unprocessed. In your case Reducer will be running `n` times.